Curl command failling with InitializeSecurityContext
I am trying to use cURL in order to call some APIs. Calling the APIs using Postman works, but with cURL it doesn't showing the error:
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (0x80090326) - This error usually occurs when a fatal SSL/TLS alert is received (e.g. handshake failed).

I am not sure how to solve it. Any ideas?

From Postman, you can generate cURL code

Copy it

Paste it to Git Bash and run it.

You can compare it with your cURL then find what was wrong.
